# gluLookAt + direction vector

Tags: opengl

I have the gluLookAt function with the following parameters:

```
gluLookAt(0.0,10.0,100.0,0.0,-10.0,-10.0,0.0,1,0,0.0);
```

My question is with the values​​: (0.0,10.0,100.0) and (0.0, -10.0, -10.0) How do I calculate the direction vector of the form (x,y,z)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your look vector:

```
vLookAt = normalize(vEye - vEyeTarget);
```

Where in your example

```
vEye = {0.0,10.0,100.0};
vEyeTarget = {0.0,-10.0,-10.0};
```